# WCF: Service that only allows a single client and rejects others

Tags: wcf, web-services, singleton

I need to create a WCF service that only allows a single client at a time. All other requests should be rejected, and the client must retry again later. The service will take around a minute to complete the request.

I've tried:

```
 [ServiceBehavior(IncludeExceptionDetailInFaults=true,
                  InstanceContextMode=InstanceContextMode.Single,
                  ConcurrencyMode=ConcurrencyMode.Single)]
```

but if I request the service multiple times (using multiple threads) in a client, I get a timeout exception on the 3rd request, but the service does actually perform the 3rd requests processing!

Comment: I believe those settings makes the calls to be queued and will be executed one after the other (since the services already has received them), what you need is that the call returns an error if is is another in process right?. I have a similar problem where I need that a single client uses the wcf channel and any other connections be refused with error codes, using the settings you mentioned and the answer below will still allow the connection and queues the calls.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could also check out the "ServiceThrottling" behavior, which allows you to specify on the server side how many concurrent instances, concurrent calls and concurrent sessions you want to support - set them all to 1, and you should have your behavior.

```
<behaviors>
  <serviceBehaviors>
     <behavior name="Throttled">
         <serviceThrottling maxConcurrentCalls="1"
            maxConcurrentSessions="1"
            maxConcurrentInstances="1" />
     </behavior>
  </serviceBehaviors>
</behaviors>
```

Marc