# Allow only a single client at a time

Tags: c#, wcf

I'm on the WCF coding now, and the question is quite standard:

I need my WCF server to manage a hardware device, so I critically need only 1 client allowed at a time. I did try some solutions found at the site, but neither

```
[ServiceBehavior(InstanceContextMode = InstanceContextMode.Single,
                 ConcurrencyMode = ConcurrencyMode.Multiple)]
```

nor the addition of

```xml
<behavior name="Throttled">
     <serviceThrottling maxConcurrentCalls="1"
     maxConcurrentSessions="1"
     maxConcurrentInstances="1" />
</behavior>
```

doesn't block me from running a 2nd application and ruining the server.

Should I learn more about client authentication or there is a magic line I can add to solve this part?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [WCF: Service that only allows a single client and rejects others](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/799307/wcf-service-that-only-allows-a-single-client-and-rejects-others)

Answer (score 0):

As I mentioned before, all those actions are not sufficient. Looks like the key is to maintain a WCF session mode -  so, I added `[ServiceContract (SessionMode = SessionMode.Required)]` with wsHttpBinding instead of basicHttpBinding (which is not allowed to maintain a session). 
Now it works.